# Show MySQL database values in DataGridView C#

Tags: c#, mysql

I made a connection to my database, but when I try to view some data from 1 table, is not showing in `dataGridView`. When I am pressing the button, few seconds seems like is going to show the values, and after that nothing posted in `dataGridView`

Can anyone explain if I made sth wrong in my code?
I am working in Visual Studio 2013

My code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string connectionString = "datasource=localhost;database=microweb;port=3306;username=root;password=pass";

    MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("select * from reservations", conn);

    try
    {
        MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter();
        sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
        DataTable dta = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(dta);
        BindingSource bdsour = new BindingSource();

        bdsour.DataSource = dta;
        dataGridView1.DataSource = bdsour;
        sda.Update(dta);

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }    
}
```

Comment: Is your datasource really named "localhost"? If so, how many (any?) records are contained in dta after the Fill?

Comment: yes, is named localhost. I made some changes in the connectionString, like another database name, pass, datasource, and is showing me some errors, like there is no database named... or password is incorrect...

Comment: I tried to use without BindingSource, and no changes....

Comment: System.DataCommon.DbDataAdapter.Fill returned  4

Comment: Did you create Columns for your datagrid?

Comment: no, I just want to see the values from table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set [`AutoGenerateColumns`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.autogeneratecolumns(v=vs.110).aspx) to true

```
bdsour.DataSource = dta;
dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
dataGridView1.DataSource = bdsour;
```

Comment: @AlexV Glad to have been of help